# Setting IIS to play mpeg dash

Tags: iis-6

I trying to setup a website to play mpeg dash(.mpd) file using IIS 6. I have created a website in IIS and trying to access it via the below web address.
http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/MPEG-DASH/scifi_trailer

But its giving me the below error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Detailed
>   Error Information Module  IIS Web Core Notification   MapRequestHandler
>   Handler   StaticFile Error Code   0x80070002 Requested
>   URL   http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:80/MPEG-DASH/scifi_trailer Physical
>   Path  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MPEG-DASH\scifi_trailer Logon Method Anonymous
>   Logon User    Anonymous

Any help on why i'm facing this issue?

Thanks,
Johm

Answer (score -1):

You need to add in the right mime type into IIS.

See https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true

You can find the correct details for the mime type from 
http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/